# Grunt.js: copy file without its parent directory

Tags: gruntjs

I am using the following in a Grunfile.js to copy *index.html* in the *exports* directory:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  copy: {
    main: {
      files: [
        {expand: true, src: ['./views/index.html'], dest: 'exports/'},
      ]
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'copy' ]);
```

What I would like to achieve is placing the file directly in the *exports* root without the *views* directory. So the path would be `/exports/index.html`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `flatten` attribute for the file config:

```
{expand: true, src: ['./views/index.html'], dest: 'exports/', flatten:true},
```